Using -split when variables are in use
I have a script something like this where I need to call a txt document that has one column where data is formatted like myid:GUID.  Myid needs to be tied to the $Display variable and GUID needs to be tied to $AccountIDs.  What you see below is what I was using but it was creating a loop so someone told me I should be using -split to separate that column and tie each part to the variables.  I need to be able to use one txt file with one column, -split that column, and use the 1st part of the split for $Display and the second part for $AccountIDs.
I have no idea how to do that.  The example I was given was "You can keep using the $display and $AccountIDs variables.  Just assign them the values from your split command:
$arr = $str -split ‘;’
$AccountIDs = $arr[0]
$Display = $arr[1]"

I don't understand how this works or where to place this in the script.  Please help.
```
$Display = Get-Content C:\Users\username\Downloads\Display.txt
$AccountId = Get-Content C:\Users\username\Downloads\AccountId.txt
foreach ($Displays in $Display){
foreach ($AccountIDs in $AccountId){

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer XXXXXX)

$body = @"
{
`"schemas`": [`"urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp`"],
`"Operations`": [
{
`"op`": `"add`",
`"value`": {
`"members`": [
{
`"display`": `"$Display",
`"value`": `"$AccountIDs"
}
]
}
}
]
}
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod '<url>' -Method 'PATCH' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json


Write-Output $AccountIDs
}
}
```


I have to admit that I didn't get you explanation. You may share some sample input data and the expected output as well to show what you're dealing with. If I got you right you may use ConvertFrom-StringData instead of -split and a loop.

If you have one column with all the data why is there two files?

Aside from your actual question, you can make $body a nested hashtable literal and convert it to json with convertto-json which will give you syntax highlighting in your IDE, and will avoid injecting unsafe values from your external files into the request body. Your $headers can be simplified to a hashtable literal as well…

If the format is myid:GUID, then why do you split on a semi-colon instead of the colon in the text? $Display, $AccountIds = $str -split ':' should then do it

Thank you all for your help. I am very new to all this and learning so I apologize for the confusion. @Theo thank you. Your answer really helped.

Hmmm ... could you solve your issue? If "yes" - how about sharing your solution with the world to help future readers comming here looking for a solution for the same or a similar issue?
